# Pass a EventHandler to a method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a eventHandler to a method.
In my method I will be using different types of eventHandlers. ie KeyDownEventHandler, ClickEventHandler and so on.

Can this be done?

@Enigmativity

Here is the full test code. Like I said I am trying to pass the EventHandlers name. as you see here it does. but when I get to the for each its just text not the true event handler. after that in the foreach loop you'll see where it should remove or add a event(subscribed or unsubscribed). when I do get it to half ways work. the unsubscribed remove eventhandler doesn't work. the way it should work is I have 6 subscribed events all the same in the form1 event += for the textbox1 to textchange to hit. when it does and I dos hit it goes to the DisableEvents method it goes throw the foreach and then when its done it goes back to the textbox1_textbox1_textchange again. 6 times. I want the DisableEvents to delete the other subscribed. depending on the last variable true or false will set it or delete it. let me know if there is anything eles I can help with to get this resolved. 
@Enigmativity
Here is the best  way to describe my issue. the form1 sets up the subscribe (+=). then in the textBox1_textChanged event I added just one line textBox1.TextChanged -= null; that's it. when I run the code 6 subscribes are setup and when I click the textbox and type anything one char, the textBox1_Changed hits. I thought the -= null should clear all subscriptions and the textbox1_Changed wouldn't rise again till I subscribe to it. where am I going wrong? Wanted it in a method so I could pass arguments. but I guess that cant sbe done or can it. Ill keep reading. Thanks

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Setup the subscribed here         

        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisableEvents(textBox1, "TextChanged", textBox1_TextChanged, false);
    }

    private static Delegate[] DisableEvents(object target, string eventName, EventHandler eventHandlerName, bool add)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Control).GetField("Event" + eventName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);

        EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = (EventHandlerList)propertyInfo.GetValue(target, null) as EventHandlerList;

        object eventKey = fieldInfo.GetValue(target);

        var _eventHandler = eventHandlerList[eventKey] as Delegate;

        if (_eventHandler == null)
            return null;

        Delegate[] invocationList = _eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (eventHandlerName item in invocationList)
        {
            if (add)
            {
                target.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).AddEventHandler(target, item);
            }
            else
            {
                target.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).RemoveEventHandler(target, item);
            }
        }
        return invocationList;
    }



//here is the example.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyEventsExample
{
public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Subscribe 8 times
        for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
        {
            textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;

            MessageBox.Show("Events added at Start # : " + c.ToString());
        }

        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //This should take the subscribed += and remove them -=.

        EventDescriptor edTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(textBox1).Find     ("KeyDown", true);

        if (ed != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ed.Attributes.Count; i++)
            {
                ed.RemoveEventHandler(textBox1, Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(KeyEventHandler), this, "textBox1_KeyDown"));
            }
        }

        //after the above is done this event should not work at all any more unless i subscribe to it again
        //But it keeps hitting the event the total of the subscried time in this case 8 times it enters in.                                                  
//when i make my method ill need a way to pass the typeof in this            case       its    the KeyEWvenHandler.

        a++;

        MessageBox.Show("Done " + a);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lets do it again
        //Subscribe 8 times
        for (int b = 0; b < 7; b++)
        {
            textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;

            MessageBox.Show("Event Button Add  # : " + b.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}
ill need to make the code in the textBox1 in to a method passing the control type  like textbox the event action like textbox_KeyDown but most of all the event handler like in the textBox1_KeyDown event its KeyEventHandler. but most of all clear all the events for the one I pass the method to.

Comment: What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Yes it can be. What's you question?

Comment: The easiest way to see if something is possible is to compile it and test it.

Comment: In my code i'm going to look at the events and ether remove them or add them. The EventHandler that im trying to define as eventHandler name will be used like this. '  foreach (eventHandlerName item in invocationList)
            {
                ctrl.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).RemoveEventHandler(ctrl, item);
            }' Like this in a foreach statement.

Comment: @Rahul, You say it can be done. Can  you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @TexG68 - It's not clear to me what you're asking. How are you expecting `DisableEvents` to work?

Comment: @TexG68 - I'm trying to understand your code, but it's not making sense to me. Can you tell what you're trying to do here from a business requirement POV (I don't want you to explain the code)?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have a event called gridviewInfo it has a event that is gridviewInfo_SelectedChange. When I'm in another part of the program I reference the gridviewInfo in that event. When i go in to this event i do a gridviewInfo.SelectedChange -= gridview_SelectedChange  which should disable that event. But it doesn't.  I have to put in to that event 3 times the -=. To disable it. So the code I put up here was a example that I was trying to make to handle all -= and +=  by calling this DisableEvent. This why Ican control it.

Comment: @TexG68 - You can't remove an event unless you have the original handler reference that you added. How are you referencing `gridview_SelectedChange `? You should show your original code because I think you've gone down this rabbit hole when we could provide you a simple fix, but I'd need to reference your original code to show you how.

Comment: I don’t use the events in the design view. I add them in method when the app first loads. That would be the += I only -= the event when I’m doing something in another event and when I’m done I turn it back on +=. It works fine for the most part. But I found a event that hits 3 times when it should have been -= off. This is why I want to look at the subscriptions and ether remove them or not. I would love to post the code here but we are talking about 6000+ lines of code. There got to be one that I didn’t -= guess that’s the next step

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between event handlers and events.

An event handler is just a delegate. It can be passed around without any problem.

Take this code:

```
Action foo = () => Console.WriteLine("1");

foo += () => Console.WriteLine("2");

foo();
```

It writes out `1` & `2` when invoked.

I can pass around `Action foo` as a parameter to any method. The gotcha is that delegates are immutable reference types. Meaning that if you modify a delegate, like my `bar += () => Console.WriteLine("3")` example below, then you have created a new delegate and the change is not reflected in `foo`. When you make a change they are no longer references to the same object.

```
Action bar = foo;

bar += () => Console.WriteLine("3");

foo();
bar();
```

So if I add that code to the original one it outputs `1`, `2`, `1`, `2`, `1`, `2`, `3`.

The original `foo` isn't modified when adding a new handler to the `bar` delegate.

So you can't affect the original delegate if you try to modify a copy you made of the reference.

Events, on the other hand, can not be passed around at all. That just the way that the compiler works. You can only attach and detach handlers to events so long as you have a reference to the original object that holds the event.

You have to resort to tricky reflection code to make passing events a possibility, but this is definitely not a straight forward approach.

There is another option that I suspect will work very well for you.

I suggest that you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework. It's like an event library on steroids.

You can do this kind of thing:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

IObservable<EventPattern<TextBox, KeyEventArgs>> keyDowns =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<TextBox, KeyEventArgs>(
            textBox, "KeyDown");

IDisposable textBoxKeyDownsSubscription =
    keyDowns
        .Subscribe(ep =>
        {
            // Use `ep.Sender` & `ep.EventArgs` here
            // Both are strongly-typed
        });
```

You attach to the event by calling `.Subscribe(...)` and you detach by calling `textBoxKeyDownsSubscription.Dispose()`.

The advantage with this approach is that you can now pass the `IObservable<EventPattern<TextBox, KeyEventArgs>>` around as a first-class citizen of the language and attach and detach subscribers without retaining a reference to the original object and without doing any reflection.

Also, you can do queries on this object using standard LINQ like operations. Now this becomes possible:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

IObservable<EventPattern<TextBox, KeyEventArgs>> keyDowns =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<TextBox, KeyEventArgs>(
            textBox, "KeyDown");

bool enabled = true;

IObservable<Keys> onlyAOrBWhenEnabled =
    from kd in keyDowns
    where kd.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.A || kd.EventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.B
    where enabled == true
    select kd.EventArgs.KeyCode;

IDisposable onlyAOrBWhenEnabledSubscription =
    onlyAOrBWhenEnabled
        .Subscribe(keyCode =>
        {
            // Use `keyCode` here
        });
```

The query `onlyAOrBWhenEnabled` performs logic on the original event and only returns keys that are either `A` or `B` when `enabled == true`. If you want to disable the event, as such, you just set `enabled = false`.

I'm not clear on what you intend `DisableEvents` to do, but if you can clarify it some more than I can produce a better example on how this can be used.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" & "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" to get the bits you need.

Comment: `The gotcha is that delegates are passed by value.` That depends entirely on the signature of the method.  If the method uses `out` or `ref`, then it's passed by reference, if it doesn't, then it's passed by value, just like every other parameter out there.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, that's true, but the OP's code is full of assignments of delegates - and compile errors. It's impossible to test to see if there is a further problem or not.

Comment: Pretty much everything you have after the line that I quoted all looks good, the reason is just wrong.  The reason that you can't change the delegate is because delegates are immutable, not because it's passed by value (you can't comment on whether it's passed by value/reference unless you have a particular method you're looking at).  If you just changed the one sentence that I quoted earlier to say, "The gotcha is that delegates are immutable" or something like that I think it would be good.

Comment: @Servy - Thank you, I didn't understand your point with your first comment. I get it now. I've changed the text in my answer. Is it good now?

Comment: No, now you've stated that it's a value type by indicating that the assignment is assigning the value of the delegate.  Delegates are reference types.  The reason for the behavior is that they're *immutable*, and that's all.

Comment: Don’t know if your talking to me or the other guy

Comment: @Servy - Thanks. I've fixed it again. :-)

Comment: Well I feel like a red headed step child. Thanks for the help I think???

Comment: @TexG68 - The key point is you should use the Reactive Framework for what you want. It makes dealing with events super simple and powerful.

Comment: @Enigmativity will that get me to where I want to be and delete drop dissolved the += events. I'll start reading. Thanks for the info ,and if you got any examples to throw my way. Would be glad to check them out.

Comment: @TexG68 - Yes, once you subscribe to an observable (which can be built from an event) you get back an `IDisposable`- then when you want to `-=` the event you just dispose of the disposable. It's dead simple.

Comment: @Enigmativity Nope that didn't work. there has to be away to stop the events when I don't need them. The -= & += I thought was going to do it but like I said if I'm in a event like textBox1_KeyDown and I reference unselect all checkboxes in gridview1. it go's to the gridview anyways and does whatever is there. even though I can handle that function in that eventim in right now"textBox1_keyDown" by refereeing that control. like gridview1.ClearAll();. Where am I going wrong. ill keep reading on the RX stuff. Look forward to your reply.

Comment: When you say "Nope that didn't work" - what didn't work? Can you post the code at the end of your question? Or perhaps make a working sample in https://dotnetfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: it is still doing the same thing. made a example for you.

Comment: it put a try catch around the  'ed.RemoveEventHandler(textBox1, Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(KeyEventHandler), this, "textBox1_KeyDown"));' it throws error   Message "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type." string

Comment: @TexG68 - please forget the delegate stuff. It won't work. Try the observable approach. It's specifically designed to let you do the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Comment: So does that mean I have to rebuild all my events to get this to work?

Comment: @TexG68 - Yes, let's chat. Can you add my user name to Skype?

Comment: Trying to setup Skype. I'm an apple user. I only use windows for VS to program. I use FaceTime all the time. I'll give it a go again. Getting late here so I'll have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get Skype to work. The video was in and out the audio was choppy. I can do FaceTime. Let me. I'll check back letter on it's about 3:20am there and almost. 11:20 here. I'll check around 11:00am there that will be 7:00pm here.

Comment: @TexG68 - I'm just interested in chatting rather than talking/video. Does that work?

Comment: Ok give me a week to do a lot of reading so when we chat I don't feel like a dumb a@$.

Comment: @TexG68 - No stress - I just want to type chat with you. You don't need to go learn stuff. I'm happy to explain as we go.

Comment: Nope you open a can of worms. Now I got to know. First stop is here. http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html

Comment: Ok @Enigmativity my questions are start to add up. Can't get skype to work. Not for sure if you can get FaceTime agoing. I do have a way that we can chat like this its my little hidden forum. Ill check in to setting up a irc for us. Got a huge powerful error server here. So why not use it. Here's my site address. http://tcb.ddns.net/forum Tty soon

Comment: Ok I'm sure i missed something in the setup but we have a irc server now. So that makes a web server Smpt server ftp server and now this. Illl have to surly change a few things around. No prob. It's just the TCB.ddns.net the router takes care all the rest or the port stuff. Let me know when you want to chat. Big difference between our times. You pick a time and ill be there. Oh just join room Rx_Framework ok this is too cool.

Comment: I activated you so you can go in and start posting msgs. I put a irc client on my iPad and ill keep checking in to see if your there.

Comment: @Enigmativity Guess you gave on me.

Comment: @TexG68 - What do you mean?

Comment: @TexG68 - I'm posting replies in the forum but they are not showing?

Comment: Down at the bottom there is a page #. Click the #2 page

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry got hit by lighting fried my surprotecter and my serever. Cost me a little over $3400.00 for new system. But its worth it to get a bigger system. The Forum is back up. Thank god for backups.

Comment: anybody have any ideals

Comment: I fugered it all by my self i used the reflections to do it. Thanks all for the help??????????

Comment: @TexG68 - What you're doing isn't a good way to go. It appears to be patching a bad design. I hoped to help you fix that.

Comment: @TexG68 - I need to see your actual code so that I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Sorry not going to happen. The examples,I gave you are the best way to show you what it looks like.

Comment: @TexG68 - That's fine. It's up to you what you want to do, but if you can share with me some actual code or at least a small working example of what you're doing then I can suggest a better way. Right now if you're using reflection like this it's probably not a great solution. You know my id on Skype. Feel free to ping me if you'd like to discuss in the future.

Comment: @Enigmativity there is a basic example here at the top. A better one on my forum. And one the reasons I'm going with the reflections is it's actually working nested of Rx framework not doing the same and one indvgual  keep telling me that its not going to work unless i give them all my code. We can do this by example and Q/A. Sorry but that's the way i feel. And believe it or not i got all my answers to reflections from here on this form. It has been about a 1/4 of bad torgage advice on reflections and the rest positive.

Comment: @TexG68 - Hey, that's no problem. I'm glad you got it working. I was just trying to help you to get a solution which I think is going to be better, but sometimes working code is 10x better that code you haven't written. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know why your getting all hurt over this. Yes i needed help an I'm open to different things. But all you gave me is i need all your code. And to boot you where telling me that i was going to half to rewrite everything into Rx. You know if you wanted to help you would lisson to what i was asking for and started small to get something to working. Don't be like this.

Comment: @TexG68 - I think you've got me wrong. I'm not hurt. I just like to help. I certainly did ask to see all your code because the code you showed me didn't seem to fit in with what you were asking about and the only way I know to give a good solution is to see the real problem in its entirety. That's why I kept asking for the code. It's the only way I think that I can really provide you with anything useful. It would also let me know how much work is required to make Rx work. It might be quite simple to retro-fit or it might be hard - but until I saw your real code I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Ok made a video for you to see what I'm doing. It is a swift format. Need to find a place to upload it. Let me know

Comment: @TexG68 - Did you email me the video in SWF format? I got an email from a satx.rr.com domain but don't want to open it in case it is spam?

Comment: Yep that was me

Comment: @Enigmativity Did you get it. I'm converting it to a class helper then a dll

Comment: @TexG68 - I can't find anything that plays a stand-alone SWF. Can you send as a mp4 or something more mainstream?

Comment: @enigmativity it's a adobe flash file that way I ca keep it small. Go to www.adobe.com search for flash player install and your good to go.

Comment: @TexG68 - I have flash installed in my browsers, but none of my browsers play the file. I think it's a new security thing.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just downloaded it and it works fine for me. Let me find a app that mp4